# Remote Debugging Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, mobile, service, remote-debugging

Trying to debug azure mobile service running in the cloud. I have published debug configuration, in the options indicated to allow debugging non JustMyCode and use source server.

Attach to running process works and I could put break points and step through the code, though I could not get the values of any variables. Even 'this' would not show the values in the watch window.

Prior to that I was trying to debug a release published configuration and the watch used to display values of some of the variables. Others were indicated that due to optimizations values are not available.

Thanks for help,
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

I think you did something wrong, because if you did the remote debug the break point should be hit and you can see all data.

Please see this article

[Cconnecting a menu app to azure mobile service > How to do the remote debugging](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/microsoft-windows-app-studio-beta-connecting-a-menu-app-to-azure-mobile-service/)

If it not help, provide a movie with that you are doing :)

I recommend to have Azure SDK 2.5 and  Visual Studio 2013 update 4